# How were Goten and Trunks able to achieve Super Saiyan so easily?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-super

As shown in the classic *Dragon Ball Z*, Goku, Vegeta and Gohan had to undergo intense training and practice before they were able to become Super Saiyan.

However, this does not seem to apply to Goten and Trunks. Although I could see Trunks also had immense training with his dad Vegeta, he still seemed to take less effort than the other 3 to turn Super Saiyan.

Also, Goten becoming a Super Saiyan doesn't make sense to me. According to the series, Goten was able to turn Super Saiyan just from being trained by Chi-Chi. How is that possible? How could Goten and Trunks (to quote Vegeta) turn SSJ like it's a Super Saiyan bargain sale?

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! I hope you don't mind me tidying up your question a bit. Since you're asking about anime, you may also be interested in the [Anime & Manga Stack Exchange](https://anime.stackexchange.com/), although this question is still perfectly on-topic here. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: I found [this from Anime & Manga Stack Exchange](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-did-goten-and-trunks-become-super-saiyan-so-easily), [and this](http://comicbook.com/anime/2017/12/01/dragon-ball-goten-super-saiyan-explanation-anime-manga/)

Answer (score 5):

An article posted on [ComicBook.com November 30, 2017](https://comicbook.com/anime/2017/12/01/dragon-ball-goten-super-saiyan-explanation-anime-manga/) features parts of an interview with Dragon Ball creator Akira Toriyama:

> Saiyans are able to tap into their true potential in two ways. First, the fighters must train often, and they must be genetically blessed with something known as S-Cells. These organic markers will determine if a Saiyan can even go Super Saiyan, and the more you have the better. According to Toriyama, "“He was able to easily become Super Saiyan thanks to inheriting lots of S-Cells".

Later it's stated that

> Gohan was born before Dragon Ball Z began, but Goten was born shortly after the Cell Games wrapped. Goku has activated his own S-Cells and accumulated more of them by the time Goten was born. So, as fans saw, Gohan’s younger brother was simply pre-disposed to the Super Saiyan form since birth.

Considering the time period, Vegeta would have also accumulated more S-Cells, thus putting Trunks in the same position to have accumulated more S-Cells.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Trunks was made before Vegeta left Earth (he achieved SSJ during his absence), and Trunks was also born before he came back for the Androids, so by that logic, Vegeta would not have accumulated enough S-Cells for Trunks?

Answer (score 2):

This is my speculation.  When the Saiyan blood mixes with humans, the resulting babies are hybrid and have a lot more potential than the original Saiyans. That's why Gohan was pretty strong for his age. Coming to Goten and Trunks, they were born when Goku and Vegeta had the super Saiyan transformation. The younger generation was a better  hybrid of Saiyan and human, and thus they are able to achieve it at a phenomenal rate compared to Goku/Vegeta.